# Error Using ng2 bootstrap in App

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am new to Angular 2, attempting to use ng2-bootstrap in my app. I followed the instructions for angular-cli getting started. Below are my app.module.ts and angular-cli.json files.

When I attempt to use the  on one of my components I get the following error 5 times:

EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'accordion' is not a known element:
1. If 'accordion' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'accordion' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

What am I missing? What steps do I need to take to incorporate ng2-bootstrap?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }                     from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }                from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LocationStrategy,
         HashLocationStrategy,CommonModule }         from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent }                 from './app.component';
import { NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES }      from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive';

import { ChartsModule }                 from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES }    from './shared/sidebar.directive';

import { AsideToggleDirective }         from './shared/aside.directive';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent }         from './shared/breadcrumb.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { SupplierDataService } from './services/supplier-data.service';
import { Angular2FontawesomeModule} from 'angular2-fontawesome';
import { AccordionModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/accordion';


// Routing Module
import { AppRoutingModule }             from './app.routing';

// Layouts
import { FullLayoutComponent }          from './layouts/full-layout.component';

// Http
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ChartsModule,
        DashboardModule,
        Angular2FontawesomeModule,
        HttpModule,
        AccordionModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FullLayoutComponent,
        NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
        BreadcrumbsComponent,
        SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
        AsideToggleDirective
    ],
    providers: [SupplierDataService,
    {
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    }],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.5.10",
    "name": "core-ui"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "scss/style.scss",
        "../vendor/styles/wijmo.css",
        "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
        "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css",
        "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-material.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [    "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)"
],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use `accordion` tag?

Comment: Why do you import `CommonModule` if you have already imported `BrowserModule`?

Comment: This was the project seed I was given, is only BrowserModule needed?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-browser-vs-common-module

Comment: looks like you're doing things correctly... i started with ng2-bootstrap but was having a number of issues so I moved to ng-bootstrap, which is developed by the angular ui guys (angular 1 wrapper)... and i've had no problems since .... (ng-b a bootstrap v4 wrapper only whereas ng2-b claims to be 3 & 4)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed **bootstrap.js** file that you have to import inside scripts in **angular-cli.json**.

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
```

Comment: no you shouldn't do this as the ng2 wrapper has its own JS to take care of the ng2 components

Comment: and accordion is an ng2 component/directive... nothing to do with Bootstrap itself